# IIS Rewrite Showing Subdirectory Name In URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis, iis-8

- I have a directory at etreecycle.co.uk/austincollins/.
- I want to point the subdomain austin.etreecycle.co.uk to /austincollins/.
- Inside /austincollins/ there is a folder called /test/.
- So to get to /austincollins/test/ the url should be austin.etreecycle.co.uk/test/.
- But the url shows as austin.etreecycle.co.uk/austincollins/test/.

## Here is the Rewrite rule:

```html
<rule name="austin.etreecycle.co.uk" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^austin.etreecycle.co.uk$" />
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/austincollins/" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="\austincollins\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

## How can I remove the /austincollins/ from the URL, and why is is showing?

Also:
When you go to austin.etreecycle.co.uk it shows the index file in /austincollins/. This is why I don't understand why you have to go to austin.etreecycle.co.uk/austincollins/dev/ and not just /dev/.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want IIS to modify the returned HTML ? or IIS to do rewriting ? when you go to  austin.etreecycle.co.uk/test/index.html does IIS show you index.html contains in /austincollins/test/index.html (this is what the specified rule should do)?

Comment: @CyrilDurand When I go to /test/index.html it returns a 404 error. I have to go to /austincollins/test/index.html. I don't want to have to put the /austincollins/ in the URL.